# can't run Android studio code on nexus 6p

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-6p

Everything goes fine when I run my program on My Samsung Galaxy which is android 4
but today I change it to Nexus 6P ， errors happened。I put the logcat follow ：

---

```
12-20 22:19:15.898 27998-28013/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xffffb041a80000 in tid 28013 (RenderThread)
    12-20 22:19:15.903 27998-28022/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7f65400008 in tid 28022 (hwuiTask1)
    12-20 22:19:16.001 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    12-20 22:19:16.001 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:6.0.1/MMB29M/2431559:user/release-keys'
    12-20 22:19:16.001 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
    12-20 22:19:16.001 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
    12-20 22:19:16.001 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: pid: 27998, tid: 28013, name: RenderThread  >>> com.sinyuk.jianyimaterial <<<
    12-20 22:19:16.001 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xffffb041a80000
    12-20 22:19:16.015 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x0   41a800004e7ed24c  x1   4effffb041a80000  x2   0000007f65272a10  x3   0000000000000000
    12-20 22:19:16.015 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x4   00000000ffffffff  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
    12-20 22:19:16.016 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x8   00000000000000c8  x9   0000007f79e7c803  x10  0000000000000076  x11  0000000000000000
    12-20 22:19:16.016 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000000  x13  0000000000000002  x14  0000000000000003  x15  0000000000000017
    12-20 22:19:16.016 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000000000000003  x17  0000000000000000  x18  000000000000000d  x19  0000007f75239940
    12-20 22:19:16.016 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f65272800  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000000000000000  x23  0000007f703ec000
    12-20 22:19:16.016 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f79e7c790  x25  0000000000000001  x26  0000007f79e7c6c1  x27  0000007f6525ad78
    12-20 22:19:16.016 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007f79e7c590  x30  0000007f700508c4
    12-20 22:19:16.017 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f79e7c590  pc   0000007f700508e0  pstate 0000000020000000
    12-20 22:19:16.040 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    12-20 22:19:16.040 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000cba8e0  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (SymbolManager::createNewSymbol(SymbolType const&, SymbolFreq, unsigned int)+84)
    12-20 22:19:16.040 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000cba8c0  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (SymbolManager::createNewSymbol(SymbolType const&, SymbolFreq, unsigned int)+52)
    12-20 22:19:16.218 3835-3835/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
    12-20 22:19:16.218 3835-3835/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
    12-20 22:19:16.323 379-379/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/27998/oom_score_adj; errno=2
    12-20 22:19:18.016 10901-10961/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser
    12-20 22:19:18.491 28033-28033/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    12-20 22:19:18.491 28033-28033/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    12-20 22:19:18.712 10901-10961/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for browser
    12-20 22:19:18.715 10901-10961/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for browser
    12-20 22:19:18.784 28033-28082/? E/chromium: [ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(243)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
    12-20 22:19:19.217 28065-28091/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
    12-20 22:19:19.217 28065-28091/? E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

---

And the build.gradle is

---

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

}
```

---

And I don't know what went wrong,any help will be  appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to access the craptastic S-browser? `com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.browser` -- that obviously (and thankfully) won't exist on a non-Samsung device. Post your code for `getUpdates()`.

Comment: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) is not a Java error but either an NDK error or some other low level C/C++ error. It is usually caused by third party libraries and is not easy to trace down. You'll have to comment out libraries and related code one by one to isolate it.